# Is the following a Bijective Function?

Tags: functions

In a bijective function is it necessary that all the elements of the domain correspond to a value in the range? Like for example can the following be a bijective function - [image: Function]

If not then what type of function is it?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: The domain of a function is the set of all possible inputs, which in the depicted case is $\{1,2,3,4\}. \qquad$

Comment: Bijection between which sets?  As the comments and answers show, there's some ambiguity here.

Comment: It's not a function at all

Answer (score 1):

As per the diagram, it's not a function. A function assigns to every value $x$ in domain (which from the diagram seems to be the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$)  a unique value in Co-domain (which seems to be equal to range from the diagram). Therefore, in your case, $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\to \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ is  not a function.

However, if you consider restriction of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4\}$, then yes, $g:\{1,2,3,4\}\to \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ is a bijection in the way your diagram shows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bijection from the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to the set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}.$

It is NOT a bijection from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}.$